# Автозаполнение Логина и пароля Android Samsung

Tags: java, android, samsung

Попытался найти информацию о автозаполнении логина и пароля, но кроме строки кода:

```
   android:importantForAutofill="yes"
   android:autofillHints="password"
```

ничего не нашел. После добавления строк, появилась строка автозаполнения, но при нажатии на кнопку **"сохранить"** пишет **"Samsung Pass не может распознать приложение**". Как можно реализовать автозаполнение? И по возможности сохранял гугл тоже

---

[image: Авторизация]

Comment: Возможно что никак: "Примечание: Samsung Pass работает только с Samsung Internet и другими поддерживаемыми приложениями." https://www.samsung.com/ru/support/mobile-devices/how-to-set-up-and-use-samsung-pass-on-your-galaxy-phone/

Comment: Протестируйте свое приложение в эмуляторе, возможно все просто работает.